# Load random index from ArrayList of custom object

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist, artificial-intelligence

I am doing my final Matric project and I am stuck. Basically what my app does is it plots a study schedule for you. My cousin gave me the idea of looping through a couple of times, generating about 10 study schedules and assigning values to them and the highest value is the chosen timetable to give to the user.

I am trying to generate a random table, where it plots the timetable with some preloaded subjects, their exam dates and their score (% the user got) which will all be populated later dynamically. I am just testing now.

My issue I am facing now is: It only loads the first subject, it does not set the next subject. I have tried to put in constraints such as the maximum amount of time that can be allocated to the one subject, but it does not work for some reason (probably bad code).

So what needs to happen is it needs to see how long we have to study per subject according to what subject is before the other in terms of exam dates (so english more than IT for example which is where the score comes in. That was inverted from the lowest percentage to a higher percentage).

Here is the code for the weighting class:

```
public void dayCounter() {
    days = new ArrayList<Day>();
    // loop through for how many days we have to study
    for(int i = 0; i < nodays; i++) {
        // create new day object to store data in
        DateTime d = startDate.plusDays(i);
        // create new day with how many hours we have to study that day
        Day day = new Day(2);
        // set the date and time for the new day object
        day.setDateTime(d);
        // get monday - sunday, what day it is
        DateTime.Property dayOfWeek = d.dayOfWeek();
        // set the day of the week (mon - sun) as name of day object
        day.setName(dayOfWeek.getAsText());
        for(int j = 0; j < day.getMaxNumberOfHours(); j++ ) {
            Subject sub = getSubject();
            try {
                if(sub != null && !sub.isAreHoursCompleted()) {
                    ArrayList<Subject> hoursPerDay = null;
                    if(sub.getExamDate().isBefore(day.getDateTime())) {
                        hoursPerDay = new ArrayList<Subject>();    
                        for(int x = 0; x < day.getMaxNumberOfHours(); x++) {
                            hoursPerDay.add(null);
                        }    
                        sub.subjectByHoursAndDays.put(i, hoursPerDay);
                        sub.totalHoursStudied++;
                    }
                    day.setSubject(sub.getName());
                    day.hours.set(j, sub);

                    hoursPerDay.set(j, sub);
                } else {
                    if(sub.isAreHoursCompleted()) {
                        int index = subjectsSortedByDate.indexOf(sub.getName());
                        subjectsSortedByDate.remove(index);
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
        days.add(day);
    }
    System.out.println(days.toString());
}

public Subject getSubject() {
    Subject s = null;
    if(rand.nextDouble() > 0.5) {
        // Assuming subjects are sorted by need to study most
        for(int i = 0; i < subjectsSortedByDate.size(); i++) {
            // get the current subject in the list
            Subject subjectToChoose = subjectsSortedByDate.get(i);
            // check if the hours are completed
            if(!subjectToChoose.areHoursCompleted) {
                // if the hours are not completed set the current subject
                s = subjectToChoose;
                // subject is set, so break out of for loop
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // get a random number in the subjects arraylist
        int index = rand.nextInt(subjects.size());
        subjects.set(index, subjects.get(index));
    }
    return s;
}
```

The line that initializes `rand` is:

`rand = new Random((int) System.currentTimeMillis());`

Also, how can I make sure that once the exam has happened, you do not need to study for that subject anymore?

Thanks in advance!
Josh

Comment: You've posted way too much code, no one will read that all. Try to get a more precise question and only link the relevant parts of the code that you are unsure of.

Comment: I have edited to code, is it any better?

Comment: The day counter method

Comment: One major problem is your incessant spurious comments. Nearly all of your comments are actually unhelpful, distracting a reader and not actually helping comprehension at all. Comments are for explaining _why_ you did something, now _what_ or _how_ you did it.

Comment: @AJMansfield I understand that, but that is how my teacher want's me to comment my code, so I have to for marks.

Comment: @Josh But there are some places where you _should_ have a comment but don't. Like the empty `catch(Exception e){}` block -- you need to document exactly why you thought you needed to catch exceptions here, and whatever made you think silencing exceptions that way was a good idea (trust me, it's not). You are also missing appropriate javadoc comments, which are actually far more important to comprehension than comments on the code itself.

Comment: @AJMansfield, I am sorry. I am a high school student, not an expert programmer. I do not understand all of this. All I want is help with the issue stated above.

Comment: Is the problem that getSubject() always returns the same subject? Please show the line that initializes rand.